# ssh wait for prompt and exit

Tags: linux, ssh, here-document

What I'm trying to achieve is to test ssh connection on 2 servers behind jump server. Requirement is to actually get shell loaded (prompt) and then exit the server(connection). First I tried :

```
ssh -A -t user@192.168.1.1 \
"command1; ssh user1@server1 exit; ssh user2@server2 exit"
```

It connects and immediately exits ssh connection, before loading prompt(shell). I found workaround with:

```
ssh -A -t user@192.168.1.1 \
"command1; ssh user1@server1 <<EOF
EOF
ssh user2@server2 <<EOF
EOF
"
```

by using EOF it actually expects some commands, therefore waits for prompt, and since there are none, exits.

Is there better/nicer way how to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Just FYI, there are much easier ways of using jump hosts: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two

Comment: I'm famliar with ProxyJump option, but this would be useful if I want just to connect, but what I need is connect, run couple of commands and see output of these commands, so again same problem - how to connect via jump server to destination server, run commands and see output - all in one line/command ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't want to use config file for that, because this will be used by more people on couple of computers (don't want to update all that every time I make some change), I came to this solution:

```
ssh -A -t user@server1 \
"command1
echo -e "command2" | ssh user1@server2
echo -e "command3" | ssh user2@server3"
```

this gets me exactly output I need in a nice format

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternate way for this which is called `.ssh/config`

create a file called .ssh/config with below edit

```
Host Server-Jump-*
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa # -- if you want to provide key
    ForwardAgent yes
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 12

Host Server1 
    Hostname 21.19.6.19
    Port 2222

Host Server2 
    Hostname Server2-IP
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p Server1
```

Save this file.

Now try this below command

`ssh Server2`

The section proxycommand description

```
-W host:port
             Requests that standard input and output on the client be forwarded to host on port over the secure channel.  Implies -N, -T, ExitOnForwardFailure and ClearAllForwardings.  Works
             with Protocol version 2 only.

`%h` Host name to connect 
`%p` Port name to connect
```

Comment: What do `%h` and `%p` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a fully automatic connection-exit process and you don't need anything that would come from stdin. So, why not close stdin?

```
<&- ssh -A -t user@192.168.1.1 "
    command1
    ssh user1@server1
    ssh user2@server2
"
```

If you get strange errors with `command1` because stdin is closed, you can replace `<&-` with `< /dev/null`